# Pivot the data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table data

```
ID        Night_111    NightOT_112   NightLeave_113
----------------------------------------------------
1          8.00         0.00           0.00            
2         16.00         4.00           0.00     
3          8.00         0.00           2.00
```

I want that table to convert it into this structure:

```
ID     wageType   hours
---------------------------
 1        111        8
 2        111       16
 2        112        4
 3        111        8
 3        113        2
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: where do you get wageType from?

Comment: substring of the column Night_111,Night_112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, but I advocate using `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (id, 111, Night_111), (id, 112, NightOT_112), (id, 113, NightOT_112)
     ) v(ID, wageType, hours)
where v.hours > 0;
```

You can do something similar using `union all` or `unpivot`.  However, `apply` implements something called a lateral join, which is a very powerful operator and useful many other situations.

Comment: What about if you have hundreds of wagetype column?

Comment: @piyushjain . . . Then you'll have hundreds of values in the `values()` clause.

Comment: @piyushjain . . . Of course.  You can put anything into a dynamic query.